# How can I set desktop defaults for new users?

Tags: desktop, defaults

How can I set up desktop defaults, much like most distributions do, for every new user?
(ex. default wallpaper, apps, etc)

Answer (score 4):

When a new user and his home directory are created, the home directory is "inititalized" with the contents of `/etc/skel`.

So if you setup a desktop like you want it to be for new users and then copy the relevant config-files to `/etc/skel`, that's what the desktop will look like for new users.

Comment: so, i'm guessing that most distributions would do this kind of thing?

Comment: @rxu not really, this is usually left to the administrator to do. The distributions "hard-wire" their stuff (branding) into separate packages, that live in the same place as the actual programs (usually in `/usr`, particularly `/usr/share` as most of the stuff is just data).